# How can I prevent WebKit browser to submit a form when enter is pressed in an input

Tags: html, safari, google-chrome, webkit, submit

When using a form with many text input, WebKit/Safari/Google Chrome submits the form when ''enter'' is pressed in any input element. Even if there is no submit input element and no *onclick* handler registered.

See for instance this sample code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action=".">
            <ul>
                <li><input type="text" name="foo" value="<?=rand()?>"/></li>
                <li><input type="text" name="bar" value="<?=$_POST['foo']?>"/></li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

When pressing enter in any of the two text input elements, the form is submitted.

Since I'm handling my form in JavaScript with asynchronous HTTP requests, I need to prevent this behavior. I could register a custom handler for the *keypressed* event to *preventDefault* and *stopPropagation* . But its seems ugly and is not really practical when new text input elements are added dynamically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Listen for the `onsubmit` event on the form and return `false`.

Comment: Damn, I was a minute too slow

Answer (score 4):

If you don't ever want the form to submit, don't include a <form> element at all. It's valid to include free-standing form field elements.

```
value="<?=$_POST['foo']?>"
```

XSS vulnerability. You need to htmlspecialchars() all text-to-HTML output.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind if you go down this route is that some browsers won't attempt to remember the form data > No auto complete.

Answer (score 1):

Daniel A. White is right, but since I got a little bit confused by the answer, maybe it should be clearly stated that the return false should be on the event:

```
function goWithSubmit(e)
{
  if (e) e.returnValue=false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering why `onsubmit="return false;"` wasn't working.